# restructure string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this string in which i need to re-structure using JavaScript.

> Label=11121212&TopicArn=test&AWSAccountId.member.1=YYYYYYY&ActionName.member.1=createTopic&Action=AddPermission&Version=2010-03-31&**AWSAccessKeyId**=XXXXXXXXX&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&Timestamp=2012-05-02T16%3A06%3A09.000Z&Signature=C3uIh%2Bz%2Fik

For this example, `AWSAccessKeyId` should be the first part of the string and `label` should be 2nd last. There are others as well, similar to this.

Expected output --AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXX&AWSAccountId.member.1=YYYYYYYYY&Action=AddPermission&ActionName.member.1=Publish&Label=ios-sns-permission-label&Signature=dEaNL0ibP5c7xyl4qXDPFPADW0meoUX9caKyUIx1wkk%3D&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2012-05-02T00%3A51%3A23.965Z&TopicArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-east-1%3A335750469596%3AiOSGoesWooooo-1335919882&Version=2010-03-31

Code that creates this incorrect string

```
exports.generatePayload = function(params, accessKeyId, secretKey, endpoint) {
    var host = endpoint.replace(/.*:\/\//, "");
    var payload = null;

    var signer = new AWSV2Signer(accessKeyId, secretKey);
    params = signer.sign(params, new Date(), {
        "verb" : "POST",
        "host" : host,
        "uriPath" : "/"
    });

    var encodedParams = [];
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params[key] !== null) {
            encodedParams.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
        } else {
            encodedParams.push(encodeURIComponent(key));
        }
    }
    payload = encodedParams.join("&");
    return payload;
}
```

I tried putting this in an array and restructure it but it didn't work for me.

Please advice how this can be done easily using JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean when you say you tried putting it in an array and restructure?  Can you post code?  That should work.

Comment: So i have and array that contains all elements of the string and i do a join to get it as a string like this ---d = [];
d.push("label=11111"); 
return e = d.join("&")

Comment: Show the expected output.  Are you dropping the rest of the string?

Comment: Include your full code, not a partial.

Comment: i have added the expected output, please ignore the values they may be different, key's is what matters

Comment: Using push and join the way you have written will work.  Please show the entirety of what you tried for that.

Comment: i have added more code that generates the string

Comment: Instead of doing a for loop, if you know the parameters you could add them explicitly.  In whatever order you want.

Comment: no the paramters are passed by user and i have no control on the order which it is passed. I can only change the array only after it is processed

Comment: It doesn't matter the order.  if (params["AWSAccessId] !== null){add_to_your_array_here} -- just do a series of these if statements.

Comment: how does that ensure that "AWSAccessId" comes at first index?

Comment: If you do it the way I posted as an answer, rather than using any loop at all, then it's simply going to check for it in the order that you declare. if["key_1"],if["key_2"],etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.generatePayload = function(params, accessKeyId, secretKey, endpoint) {
    var host = endpoint.replace(/.*:\/\//, "");
    var payload = null;

    var signer = new AWSV2Signer(accessKeyId, secretKey);
    params = signer.sign(params, new Date(), {
        "verb" : "POST",
        "host" : host,
        "uriPath" : "/"
    });

    var encodedParams = [];
    if(params["AWSAccessKeyId"] != null)
    {
        encodedParams.push(encodeURIComponent("AWSAccessKeyId") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params["AWSAccessKeyId"]));

    }
    if(params["AWSAccountId.member.1"] != null)
    {
        encodedParams.push(encodeURIComponent("AWSAccountId.member.1") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params["AWSAccountId.member.1"]));

    }
    //other_ifs_for_param_keys_here
    payload = encodedParams.join("&");
    return payload;
```

Comment: There are more efficient ways of doing this, but this will work.